# jar command not working in java while trying to extract file

Tags: java

When I try to unjar the files into my webapp folder using command prompt it keeps throwing error.

```
C:\Users\Jamuna\workspace1\TestSolr\webapp>java -jar -xvf C:\Users\Jamuna\Deskto
p\apache\apache-solr-4.0.0\dist\apache-solr-4.0.0.war
```

> Unrecognized option: -xvf

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Please let me know why this is happening???

Comment: first google result http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

Comment: Have you set the JAVA environment variables in PATH and JAVA_HOME correctly

Comment: you're trying to unpack your war file?

Answer (score 3):

You should run jar.exe, not java.exe. jar.exe should be in JDK/bin directory, i.e.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\jar.exe -xvf apache-solr-4.0.0.war
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the

```
java -jar my-own-jarfile.jar
```

(which launches a properly prepared application) and the

```
jar -xvf my-own-jarfile.jar
```

(which extracts the contents of a jar file) commands.  I've done the same more than once.